# When using the A-Frame Log Component how can I prevent the logs from displaying again on the console?

Tags: aframe

When using the log component, I want to disable the redundant logging on the console. I notice this appears to be supported by the component:
https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/blob/master/components/log/index.js#L22

However I'm not sure how to set that system variable on my A-Frame scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a-scene log="console: false">`